# Writing on a already opened CSV file from R studio

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file named output.csv, saved in my working directory & opened...
When I use write command in R for writing on that opened CSV file, i am getting an error as

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '1file.csv': Permission denied
```

It is very important that the file remains opened....
Plz help

Comment: can you write to another file until it's closed?

Comment: Yes i need to write on an opened file...

Answer (score 1):

For writing to files open with excel I use

```
write.table(dataobject,file="clipboard",sep="\t")
```

Then go to excel and do a control v, where dataobject is the data object that you want to write! This basically copies and pastes to excel

Comment: But this way only the last value of the table is copied... There are no. of rows that needs to copied... R has to write dynamically into excel while excel is being opened.... is this possible?

Comment: what are you trying to copy a dataframe? Vector?, I usually use this method to copy and paste data frames and it copies the whole dataframe (as long as its not too big) not just the last row. can you post an example.